# Adding onClick listener without knowing the layout views and ID's (Android)

Tags: android, layout, button, view, listener

Hi I'm new to android programming, I'm trying to initiate the on click method for all the buttons in my layout. I've wrote the following code :

```
public class SudokuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     setAllOnClick();
 }

 private void setAllOnClick(){

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    ArrayList<View> touchables = ll.getTouchables();

    for (View v : touchables){
        if (v instanceof Button){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((Button) v).getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
  }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((Button) v).getText() ,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

The toast in the for works great - meaning I menage to get all the instances of my buttons, 
but the toast in the onClick method doesn't work, in fact I've seen in the debugger that it never reaches the onClick method, but I can't figure out why ?
Thanks, and sorry if it's too nooby, or if I haven't noticed something very stupid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is your inflating a new view and adding the click listeners to that, you want to add the listeners to the view on the screen.

Here this works:

```
@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();

    FrameLayout ll = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    ArrayList<View> touchables = ll.getTouchables();

    for (View v : touchables){
        if (v instanceof Button){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((Button) v).getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

}
```

> onContentChanged()
>
> This hook is called whenever the content view of the screen changes (due to a call to Window.setContentView or Window.addContentView).

Comment: Hehe ;-) and I was dawdling :p

Comment: As far as I understand "android.R.id.content" should be my layout where the buttons are? but when i put there my LinerLayout id (R.id.button_holer_linear_layout), it throws an exception. Is there another way to get the current activity view and iterate over its elements?

Comment: Don't change any of the code, use it as above. android.R.id.content is the ID reference for the layout that you have used with setContentView() (which is your R.layout.main) it needs to be cast to a FrameLayout and it'll work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

waaaaait... you are inflating a new instance of the content view and setting the listener on THOSE, not the ones that are on screen. Your problem is with these lines:

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

Basically you are making a copy of the stuff on your screen, that's why it's not working.

What you want to do is go in the XML, set an ID for the linear layout you are trying to get and then use [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) to get a reference to it instead of those two lines. You need to get really aquinted with findViewById, you're going to use it a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

How about you attach breakpoint on v.setOnClickListener(this); and step over and inspect the view to see what's the current registered event listener?

I am not sure if its indeed your entire class or an extracted snippet so: 
you should double check if 'this' in v.setOnClickListener(this); is indeed your activity. Use SudokuActivity.this to be sure.

Also, make sure your button are clickable:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable

You may have inadvertently copied the layout from some other layout file in your project?

Answer (score -1):

Use a switch case in your `onClick()`

```
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonId:
        // do the toast here
    break;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't reach the onClick? and I don't know why. I wont leave the toast there it's just for now